# Palindrome Checker Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, c, palindrome

Here is an example of how I solved this problem (though this is not the only nor the best way by any means) for an assignment where it was also requisite to determine if a string was a reverse prefix of the other. Obviously a palindrome is a reverse prefix of itself so if you can determine a reverse prefix then you can determine a palindrome.

I would love some feedback on my code as well as any thoughts on my implementation/solution.

```
int main()
{
    char string1[50];
    char string2[50];

    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    gets(string1);
    if (strlen(string1) == 1)
        exit(1);
    printf("Please enter a second string: ");
    gets(string2);
    printf("\nString 1 = %s", string1);
    printf("\nString 2 = %s\n", string2);
    if (isReversePrefix(string1, string2))
        printf("String 2 is a reversed prefix of string 1\n");
    if (isPalindrome(string1))
        printf("String 1 is a palindrome\n");
    else
        printf("String 1 is not a palindrome\n");
    if (isPalindrome(string2))
        printf("String 2 is a palindrome\n");
    else
        printf("String 2 is not a palindrome\n");
    return 0;
}
/************************************************
 isReversePrefix - Receives two string pointers
 and determines if the second is a reverse
 prefix of the first. Returns either true or
 false.
 The word 'HIM' has the following prefixes 'H', 'HI',
 'HIM'. All of these can be reversed to 'H', 'IH', 'MIH'
 ************************************************/
int isReversePrefix(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    char *temp1 = str1;
    char *temp2 = str2;

    if (strlen(str2) > strlen(str1))
        return 0;

    strrev(temp2);
    while ((*temp1 == *temp2) && (*temp2 != '\0'))
    {
        temp1++;
        temp2++;
    }
    if (*temp2 == '\0')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
/************************************************
 isPalindrome - receives one string parameter and 
 checks if it is a palindrome or not. Returns
 true if it is and false if not.
************************************************/
int isPalindrome(char *str1)
{
    char *start = str1;
    char *end = str1 + strlen(str1) - 1;
    if (isReversePrefix(start, end))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `str2.strlen()`??? what kind of C code is this? I'm having a hard time believing this compiles...

Comment: If you are using all string functions, why not strcmp to reduce your code :)

Comment: thepace: Your suggestion is 100% correct. If I remember correctly the assignment prohibited us from using strcmp because a requirement and code not included in this post was to write our own version of comparing two strings.

Comment: glampert: I edited the code from the original copy/paste and was in the OOP dot notation frame of mind rather than the STL strlen(char*) frame of mind. Major goof up on my part. Above code is edited.

Comment: Still has `temp2.strrev();`.

Comment: See the other algorithm and my attempt [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74249/determining-if-a-sentence-is-a-palindrome) about checking if the sentence is palindrome.

Answer (score 2):

- Since the `char` array sizes are fixed, you should make sure the inputs are of an appropriate size before continuing.  This should best be done with the function doing the reading.

  **Very important**: [`gets()` is unsafe as it has no knowledge of buffer size thus is vulnerable to buffer overflow](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1049157810&id=1043284351).  Instead, use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), which is safer as it takes a buffer size as an argument.
- Consider hard-coding the `50` to make its intent clear.

  ```
  #define MAX_LENGTH 50
  ```
- Since you're already in `main()`, you can use `return 1` instead of `exit(1)`.
- Unformatted strings like this:

  > ```
  > printf("Please enter a string: ");
  > ```

  can instead be output using [`puts()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454474/what-is-the-difference-between-printf-and-puts-in-c):

  ```
  puts("Please enter a string: ");
  ```

  Be aware that `puts()` automatically appends a newline at the end.  If you don't want this newline, then you can use [`fputs()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fputs.htm) instead:

  ```
  fputs("Please enter a string: ", stdout);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

1. These functions should be able to handle constant arrays.

   ```
   // int isReversePrefix(char *str1, char *str2)
   int isReversePrefix(const char *str1, const char *str2)
   ```
2. By calling `strlen(str2) > strlen(str1)`, code is marching down each string twice.  Only need to find the end of one.

   ```
   int isReversePrefix(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
     const char *p2 = str2[strlen(str2)];

     while (*str1 && p2 > str2) {
       p2--;
       if (*str1 != *p2) {
         return 0;
       }
       str1++; 
     }

     return *str1 == '\0' && p2 == str2;
   }
   ```
3. Now that `isReversePrefix()` handles constant strings, `isPalindrome()` is easy:

   ```
   int isPalindrome(char *str1) {
     return isReversePrefix(str1, str1);
   }
   ```
4. Original `isPalindrome()` has 2 problems: Consider what happens when `str1 == ""`

   ```
   char *end = str1 + strlen(str1) - 1;
   if (isReversePrefix(start, end))
   ```
5. Calling `isReversePrefix()` with `isReversePrefix(start, end)` simple will not work.  The code is only checking if the first `char` of the string matches its end.
6. Original `isReversePrefix()` reverses the contents of `str2`.  This may be an very unhappy side effect for an application calling `isReversePrefix()`
7. An efficient re-write of `isPalindrome()` would find the length and then do `length/2` compares.